# Kivy: MDIconButton not centering in Gridlayout and MDLabel with button behavior cannot be moved

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, python-3.8, kivymd

I'm new to Kivy and I want to make a signin screen for my app. I have two problems. First, inside my Gridlayout I have 3 MDIconbuttons and they cannot seem to be centered no matter what I try. Second, I want the MDLabel with the text "Forgot your password/username?" to be closer to the MDTextFieldRound I have above, but putting in negative padding moves the text, but not the button behavior.

main.py

```
import kivy 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

class SignInScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ButtonGrid(ButtonBehavior, BoxLayout):
    pass

class AttendanceApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "LightBlue"
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Red"
        return SignInScreen()
    def change_theme(self, primary_palette, accent_palette):
        pass
        #theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    def signin_pressed(self, instance):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    AttendanceApp().run()
```

Attendance.kv

```
# Filename: Attendance.kv

#:import utils kivy.utils

#screens

<SignInScreen>
    #change_theme: app.change_theme("Bright Blue", "Red")
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .75}
        size_hint: .8, 1
        spacing: dp(25)


        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: username
            icon_right: "email"
            helper_text: "Email"
            normal_color: .4, .4, .4, .4

        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: password
            icon_right: "key"
            helper_text: "Password"
            password: True
            normal_color: .4, .4, .4, .4

        ButtonGrid:
            size_hint: .9, None
            height: 10
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
            on_press: print(self.pos)

            BoxLayout:

                MDLabel:
                    valign: "top"
                    text: "Forgot your password/username?"
                    halign: "center"
                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                    font_style: "Caption"
                    text_color: .4, .4, .4, .4

        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text: "Sign In"
            custom_color: .17, .24, .98, 1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: .9, None
            height: 25
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
            padding: 0, 0, 0, -50

            MDLabel:
                text: "Or sign in with"
                halign: "center"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                font_style: "Caption"
                text_color: .4, .4, .4, 1


        GridLayout:
            padding: 0, 10, 0, 0
            spacing: dp(25)
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: 1
            cols: 3
            halign: "center"
            canvas:

                Color:
                    rgba: .4, .4, .4, 1

                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos

            MDIconButton:
                icon: "google"
                user_font_size: "32sp"
                elevation_normal: 12
                md_bg_color: .4, .4, .4, .2

            MDIconButton:
                icon: "facebook-box"
                user_font_size: "32sp"
                elevation_normal: 12
                md_bg_color: .4, .4, .4, .2

            MDIconButton:
                icon: "twitter"
                user_font_size: "32sp"
                elevation_normal: 12
                md_bg_color: .4, .4, .4, .2
```

Right now the Application looks like this:
[Application Screen Signin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gViC.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MDIconButton` has a fixed size and the `GridLayout` will set its column width according to the `MDIconButton` width, which ends up putting all the `MDIconButtons` to the left.

You can use `AnchorLayout`, which does not have a fixed size, to contain each `MDIconButton`. The `AnchorLayouts` will each get the same share of the `GridLayout` width, and by default, places its content in the center of its area.

I have changed the `GridLayout` `height` to `self.minimum_height`, so it calculates its `height` based on the children `heights`. And the `canvas` instruction is changed to handle this.

```
    GridLayout:
        padding: 0, 10, 0, 0
        spacing: dp(25)
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.minimum_height
        cols: 3
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: .4, .4, .4, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.width, 1
                pos: self.x, self.y+self.height-1

        AnchorLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: but1.height
            MDIconButton:
                id: but1
                icon: "google"
                user_font_size: "32sp"
                elevation_normal: 12
                md_bg_color: .4, .4, .4, .2

        AnchorLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: but2.height
            MDIconButton:
                id: but2
                icon: "facebook-box"
                user_font_size: "32sp"
                elevation_normal: 12
                md_bg_color: .4, .4, .4, .2

        AnchorLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: but3.height
            MDIconButton:
                id: but3
                icon: "twitter"
                user_font_size: "32sp"
                elevation_normal: 12
                md_bg_color: .4, .4, .4, .2
```